# How to give scroll to gridview inside vertical scrollview in android through layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

When applying scroll to gridview inside vertical scrollview,only parent scrolling is possible but the child gridview does not scroll..

Is there any idea about this problem in android xml?

Answer (score 1):

Just Add one property to gridview will enable both scrollview and gridview to scroll.

android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutTimelineButtons">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeHeader"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <GridView
                        android:id="@+id/gridMatchedUserGallery"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgProfileBackground"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgProfileBackground"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                        android:numColumns="3" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
              </RelativeLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager ,then you can scroll your gridview(Recyclerview with gridLayout) inside scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

i think its working
change gridview in to packagename.ExpandableHeightGridView

```
<com.magazine.screens.ExpandableHeightGridView
    android:id="@+id/gv_issues"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp">
</com.magazine.screens.ExpandableHeightGridView>
```

then create new class for ExpandableHeightGridView ,here is the class

```
package com.magazine.screens;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

/**
* Created by muhammed.haris on 31-03-2017.
*/

public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView {
boolean expanded = false;

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded()) {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
}
```

and important to add this code in your class

```
gridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gv_issues);
    gridView.setExpanded(true);  //its important
```

i hope its definitely work